# Error while posting request through postman api node js

Tags: node.js, postman

I am very new to `node js` I just want to insert data into `MYSQL` database I searched into google and found this code.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//create database connection
const conn = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'auth'
});

//connect to database
conn.connect((err) =>{
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log('Mysql Connected...');
});

//add new product
app.post('/add',(req, res) => {
  let data = {name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password, contact: req.body.contact};
  let sql = "INSERT INTO registration SET ?";
  let query = conn.query(sql, data,(err, results) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results}));
  });
});

//Server listening
app.listen(3000,() =>{
  console.log('Server started on port 3000...');
});
```

but when I try to call this api or hit this api (well I don't know the exact word to be use in this situation) I am getting response in form of html, this is the error I am getting.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot POST /add/</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

I already made changes to the postman like:

under `header`  `content-type` is `application/json`

this is the body or data that I want to send

```
{ 
    "name": "Ayush",
    "email": "ayush@a.com",
    "password": "test",
    "contact": 1234567890
}
```

Comment: I guess the issue is with the trailing "/" at the end of "/add/".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sudharsan Selvaraj

I made a small change and then it worked, all I did just add `/` after `add`

```
app.post('/add/',(req, res) => {
  let data = {name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password, contact: req.body.contact};
  let sql = "INSERT INTO registration SET ?";
  let query = conn.query(sql, data,(err, results) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results}));
  });
});
```